# Get & Set MySQL Select

Tags: c#, mysql, get, set

What am i missing here, it seems the main form is not calling the method from tsDBCon class and not connecting to the database, i need help, i'm new to get:set properties, am i doing it wrong or what? thanks.

```
public class tsDBCon
    {
    private string _user;
    private string _pass;

           public string User
           {
               get 
               {
                   return _user;
               }
               set
               {
                   _user = value;
               }
           }

           public string Pass
           {
               get 
               { 
                   return _pass; 
               }
               set
               {
                   _pass = value;
               }
           }


    public void QueryUser()
        {
            tsDBCon get = new tsDBCon();  
            var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"];
            {
                string CN = connSettings.ConnectionString;
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(CN);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from users where user = @user and pass = @pass", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", get.User);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", get.Pass);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                conn.Open();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    get.User = reader["user"].ToString();
                    get.Pass = reader["pass"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }


     This is the code in Main Form
     tsDBCon ts = new tsDBCon();
     private void GetUser()
     {
      ts.User = txtUser.Text;
      ts.Pass = txtPass.Text;
     }
```

Comment: You don't have to use the get. in your tsDBCon class, just use the name of the property.

Comment: @GrantWinney alright, i have noticed that.
RonBeyer
what do you mean sir? is the get:set unnecessary?

Comment: This: get.User = reader["user"].ToString(); should be User = reader["user"].ToString(); There is no need to use get. before User or Pass, same with where you use it in the command parameters.

Comment: @RonBeyer it works, how can i validate through my main form if the values is correct sir?

Comment: It depends on what you mean, you are doing something strange passing in the username and password, then extracting it back out from the database, so I don't k now what you are trying to validate.

Comment: @RonBeyer  i want to validate if the user entered the correct user and pass through the textboxes, if im doing it wrong sir please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing here, it seems the main form is not calling the
>   method from `tsDBCon` class and not connecting to the database, I need
>   help, i'm new to get:set properties, am i doing it wrong or what?

Yes, you are doing a few things wrong.

> I want to validate if the user entered the correct user and pass through the textboxes.

Your code contains several problems:

- When you create `IDisposable` instances (e.g. a `MySqlConnection`) you need to dispose them. The easiest way to ensure this is to wrap them in a `using` block.
- If you create a local temporary instance of an object (e.g. `tsDBCon get = new tsDBCon();`) any value you assign to its properties will be gone after you leave the scope of the method you are in. Unless you return it as a function result or through a `ref` or `out` parameter.

To check if a user name / password combination is correct, from the code sample you provided, you might want to change things a bit like this:

```
public class tsDBCon
{
    private const string ExistsQuery = "select count(*) from users where user = @user and pass = @pass";

    public tsDBCon(string user, string pass)
    {
        User = user;
        Pass = pass;
    }

    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }

    public bool LoginExists()
    {
        var connSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"];
        var CN = connSettings.ConnectionString;

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(CN))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (cmd = new MySqlCommand(ExistsQuery, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", User);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Pass);
                var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return count > 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your Main Form use it like this:

```
ts = new tsDBCon(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);
userLoginExists = ts.LoginExists();
```

One last remark: **NEVER store a password unencrypted.**

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in 

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @KevinRodriguez That is because you are not doing what is in the code in this answer, but you are doing something else. There is no `tsDBCon get = new tsDBCon();` statement in this answer is there?